# Create XSD schema

Tags: excel, xml, xsd

I'm a beginner in XML/XSD so I would need some help :).

I have to create a XSD schema to import it into Excel (for a mapping) so that I can export data from Excel to a XML file.

But I have some problem to create the schema.

Here are some examples (not real data) to explain my projet.

I'll have an Excel Workbook with 4 Columns :
     - ID_Company
     - Contact_Name
     - Contact_Last_Name
     - Contact_City

So, for a same ID_Company I'll have many Contacts.

Here is what I have for now :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="contact">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Test</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Company" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="ID_Company" type="xs:integer" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                                <xs:element name="Contact" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:element name="Contact_Name" type="xs:string"/>
                                            <xs:element name="Contact_Last_Name" type="xs:string"/>
                                            <xs:element name="Contact_City" type="xs:string"/>
                                        </xs:sequence>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>   
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

So, I can import this into Excel, then I add some date to see if it works when I want to export into XML.
But, it does not... I have an error from Excel saying that it is impossible to export the XML data...

The final goal is to have ID_Compnany once with all contacts in my XML...

I don't know if I'm clear or not, do not hesitate to tell me.

Thanks in advance for all the help

Comment: Schemas, while good for validation, don't do a great job of describing what the XML should look like.  Running your schema through a XSD -> XML utility creates an XML that clearly illustrates what your schema rules imply.  In this case, your rule and your output don't match.  You're saying ID_Company should only appear once, but your schema rule says "unbounded".  Best to model a sample XML first, then build a schema (an only if absolutely necessary).  Share the same XML with others, along with a schema.  The sample really makes the communication go better.  Good Luck.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. What I meant for the ID_Company was for ID_Company = 1 I have 5 contacts, ID_Company = 2, I have 4 contacts, ID_Company = 3, I have 7 contacts and so on. So, If I understand correctly, I should start with an XML and then see if I need and XSD or not?

Comment: Any ideas? I was wondering if it could be easier/possible to do it with ACCESS. In fact, I have an XSD schema imposed by my supplier so I want to find the best way to adapte this xsd schema into Excel or Access because updating all the data manually is impossible. Too much work. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Ask the supplier to provide a sample XML, since the schema is ambiguous.  Then use MSXML, in Excel VBA, Access or C# (System.XML) to create the XML that you need.  The point is that you can't do this without a sample document, and Excel / Access won't be able to do this without custom code.